# Laravel and SQL server and database class

Tags: php, sql-server, database, laravel

I have got Laravel installed and I am trying to fetch ANY data from the SQL Server database but i keep having the same problem all the time and I am getting so frustrated because I either just don't know what I am doing or I am doing it wrong.

I've got my database connection set up after a lot of hassle with ODBC SQL Drivers for Windows. Now in my welcome.blade.php I want to fetch data from my database but everytime i try to get any data i get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\welcome.blade.php on line 9

Now I only got these two lines in my code that should fetch (I GUESS) the data:

```
<?php
    $Booking = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('fmsStage.dbo.Booking')->get();
    var_dump($Booking);
?>
```

But instead it gives me that error. And I've tried using \DB::table and also tried using just the table itself \DB::table('Booking') and also with the table prefix \DB::table('dbo.Booking') but it won't even find the whole DB class. But what am I doing wrong, I don't get it at all.

When i try to add

> use DB;

It gives me another error/warning:

> Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'DB' has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\welcome.blade.php on line 9

UPDATE: I have now created the model Booking to get data from booking. But now when i use

```
use App\Booking;
$booking = App\Booking::all();
foreach($booking as $bookings) {
    echo $bookings->agent;
}
```

It stills gives me an error on the freaking USE part...

> Fatal error: Class 'app\Booking' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\welcome.blade.php on line 10

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `$data = TABLENAME::all();` change table name with the name of  your model

Comment: I don't have a model? What does a model do?

Comment: Try Snowno answer below but like this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;`

Comment: I did as snowno said and then used that with what you just said. It still gives me this error: 
Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\welcome.blade.php on line 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
$data = DB::table("tablename")->get();
dd($data);
```

***ofcourse in your controller,not views~***

Comment: I see, can you explain what a controller is and how you go about with them, I am trying to figure out how to work with this framework. :S

Comment: In this case you will need to get at least basics as Controllers, Models, Views etc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3. Here is another http://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/

Comment: I've made the model that should read from my table. But i am still getting errors when i try to USE my model:
Fatal error: Class 'App\Booking' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\welcome.blade.php on line 10

Comment: @ThimoFranken just check links which I've posted above. They will help you a lot how to start.